# Load C# dll and find entry point

Tags: c#, dll, loadlibrary

How to load a C# dll and find the entry point from it?

I have used following code to load the library

```
    string str = @"D:\MyDLL.dll";
    str = Path.GetFullPath(str);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(str);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "find entry point" ?

Comment: Can't you just add a reference??

Comment: You can use Mono.Cecil for that, it's quite easy :)

Comment: Is MyDLL.dll .NET assembly?

Comment: Dll's don't have entry points. Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 4):

one way to do would be

```
string str = @"D:\MyDLL.dll";
str = Path.GetFullPath(str);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(str);

string args = {"a", "b"}; //command line args that you need to pass

MethodInfo publicStaticVoidMain = assembly.EntryPoint;
publicStaticVoidMain.Invoke(null, args);
```

i suggest involving a separate appdomain in the process. but that is not necessary though.

### EDIT:

From the debate that followed here is the excerpt.

1. there are different types of DLLs in the wild. you have to know excetly which type of DLL are you talking about. dot-net DLLs are different from WIN32 dll.
2. *entry-point* is usually a method defined in the dll. it is optional for either of WIN32 or dot-net.
3. dot net code is best suitable with dot-net dlls.
4. if a dot-net dll doesnt have an entry point. `assembly.EntryPoint` returns null. if it has then you can call `invoke` on the entry-point and enter in it.
5. dot-net EXEs also behave like dot-net DLL (can even be renamed and made to look like one). an EXE (even if renamed) is certain to contain that entry point.

Comment: I don't think, that DLLs have an entry point (As described here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.reflection.assembly.entrypoint.aspx))

Comment: in dot-net there is not nuch difference in exe and dll. they both are assemblies and an assembly can have a entry point. thing is that a class-library cant have an entry point but that is just because one is not specified in manifest. if it is specified (manually or somehow) then it can have. that is not the point. here @Kapil believes that his assembly has an entry point. so if there is one, he can use it in the way shown.

Comment: @black_wizard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682596(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Smartis, it is a WIN32 DLL link, not a managed dot-net dll. both are different. WIN32 dlls can have entry-points, dot-net class-libraries dont.

Comment: And here we are now... ;D @Kapil Gurav: What DLL Type do you have? Specified your Question!

Comment: @Smartis - I have a .NET DLL